# Get the previous version of a document and set the link to a field

Tags: 2013, development, document-library, versioning

How can I access the link to a previous version of a document in a library and assign that value to the new version of the document?

*eg. Version 2 has been submitted and I want a link to the pervious version (1) attached to that document.*

In addition to this, currently when the document is generated via a 3rd party it creates two versions, how can I delete the first of the two versions?

Comment: You can see the previous version of the document by going into version history of the file and right click on the file name of a specific version and select copy link address, but I was not able to open the older version of the file in owa.

Comment: so as far as you are aware there is no way to access the versioning other than the number and by manually going into the record?

Comment: Hope the code below helps you

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code I wrote in my project.

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Output-Files');
var file = list.getItemById(484).get_file()
var versions = file.get_versions();
ctx.load(versions);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(function(){
    var enumer = versions.getEnumerator();
    while(enumer.moveNext()){
        var currentItem = enumer.get_current();
        console.log(currentItem.get_url())
    }
},function(s,a){console.error(a.get_messgae())})
```

this is the url  it displayed

_vti_history/512/OutputFiles/filename.docx

you can download the file, but cannot open in OWA